# How do we handle ALTER TABLE column TYPE in Cassandra in actual scenarios?

Tags: nosql, cassandra

I'm aware of the restrictions Cassandra has on modifying column data types once table is created or even dropping and adding column with same name of different data type.
Dropping and Adding is allowed with [restrictions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html#cql_data_types_c__cql_data_type_compatibility).

But, if we talk about actual scenarios, it's not that uncommon to modify table schema during initial phase of our project.
**Example:** modifying `Name column of User table from TEXT to a UDT(User Defined Type)` that could encapsulate more information.

Coming from a RDBMS background, this is a very strange behaviour and maybe someone with actual project experience on Cassandra can answer it.

How do we handle such scenario of modifying column datatypes ? And what are the best practices.
Also, is this a common behaviour with other NoSQL or columnar databases ?

Comment: This could be common scenario where queries or table structure could be modified in future, as we work in an agile model.

Answer (score 1):

It has not been possible to change the data type of a column for over 5 years now, in fact since Apache Cassandra 3.0.11 and 3.10 ([CASSANDRA-12443](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12443)). It was done because it causes a lot of issues including nodes unable to start, unable to replay commitlog mutations and other data corruption.

Additionally, dropping then re-adding a column with the same name but with a different type also causes the same issues so it has also been disallowed ([CASSANDRA-14843](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14843), [CASSANDRA-14948](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14948)).

Recall that in Cassandra, **SSTables are immutable** -- they don't change or get updated once they've been written to disk. If changing column types was allowed, it would render data in the existing SSTables unreadable because the data no longer matches the schema.

Similarly, it would be impossible to restore the data from backups because the schema in production would not match that of the backups.

These are the reasons it is not allowed. If you attempt to run `ALTER TABLE ... TYPE`, the command will return an error similar to:

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] \
  message="Altering column types is no longer supported"
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank You for your response.Now I understand why it's not possible.

My question was more on how do we handle such scenarios in projects, where columns are to be modified or an additional field needs to be added in the UDT, etc.
Example: A column that maintains flag which was earlier boolean, but now as requirement has changed we have more statues to be handled by flag column. In RDBMS, we would consider changing the boolean column to an ENUM or VARCHAR. 
How this scenario would be handled in Cassandra ?

Comment: Add a new column with a new name and a new type. Not change an existing column. Cheers!